# Measuring experts' agreement with the textbook consensus

Tags: likert

Please help with the following case:

We are planning to compare expert and non-expert group on whether they agree/disagree with a textbook consensus. To this effect, we want to ask them to evaluate statements on a 5-point Likert scale. The more they agree with a correct statement, the closer they are to the textbook consensus, the higher the score. 
In order to compare answers of the two groups we thought of doing analysis of variance (ANOVA).

However, we are also interested whether experts' opinions group around the textbook consensus (5 on Likert scale). I suppose we can see this by looking at the distributions?

But my main question is: is there any method of measuring in-group agreement (or consistency) that could incorporate information about their closeness to the external correct answer (the textbook consensus, point 5 on the scale)?

(We are not interested in between-raters' agreement/consistency but whether they agree with the textbook consensus.)

Comment: You suggest that the textbook consensus is somehow the correct answer (rather than the consensus of your experts). That doesn't seem to be the case with introductory statistics texts (but perhaps that's an outlier); on a number of issues more than half are demonstrably wrong.